# Subscript out of range error when copying data from a workbook to another

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to copy data from one workbook to another.
i havs written below piece of code but i am getting subscript out of range error when executing below line -

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & i, Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & i).Offset(chunks - 1, c_cnt - 1)).Value = Workbooks("C:\Users\user1\Desktop\" & f_name).Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i, Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i).Offset(chunks - 1, c_cnt - 1)).Value
```

variable values:

```
i=1
chunks=10
fname="test.xlsx"
```

Comment: Is it because you're calling `f_name` yet the variable is `fname`?

Comment: i am using fname to refer to workbook, f_name is set to name of the workbook.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect is has something to do with your code just calling sheet() without specifying with workbook it should be pulling that sheet from. Try setting up variables for both of the worksheets so that you can clearly define that. This will also make that line a little easier to read if you ever need to debug it later.

```
Dim wb As Workbook, ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet

Set ws1 = Workbooks("C:\Users\user1\Desktop\" & f_name).Sheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheets2")

ws2.Range("A" & i, ws2.Range("A" & i).Offset(chunks - 1, c_cnt - 1)).Value = ws1.Range("A" & i, ws1.Range("A" & i).Offset(chunks - 1, c_cnt - 1)).Value
```

You could even go farther and define the range variables too, this might make it even more readable

```
Dim wb As Workbook, ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range

Set ws1 = Workbooks("C:\Users\user1\Desktop\" & f_name).Sheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheets2")

Set rng1 = ws1.Range("A" & i).Offset(chunks - 1, c_cnt - 1)
Set rng2 = ws2.Range("A" & i).Offset(chunks - 1, c_cnt - 1)

ws2.Range("A" & i, rng2).Value = ws1.Range("A" & i, rng1).Value
```

Comment: Even if this does not solve the problem, this is far easier to debug than the code initially posted by the OP. +1, I was about to suggest something similar in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Try select the destination worksheet prior to assigning value:

```
Workbooks("C:\Users\user1\Desktop\" & f_name).Sheets("Sheet1").select
```

(and make sure you're using the f_name or fname as you intended)